Azure synapse workspace - RBAC not working when the workspace is opened
I have just created a synapse analytics workspace, on opening it I get an error message similar to the below.

From my research, I have gr anted storage blob contributor role to the synapse application as well as the user assigned managed identity.
Going into Manage >> Access Control, I cannot seem to assign roles.
I expect a screen with all the assignment roles, but I get the below

Is there a way to view the actual error message to see what is causing the problem ?


Error: You don't have access to the serverless SQL pool, Built-in. To be granted access, contact a Synapse Administrator for this workspace.

As you mentioned you want to list with all the assignment roles
You can follow the below steps:
Step 1: Click on add roles
Step 2: Under workspace click on the dropdown to list available roles


Select the user or SPN & provide the required role.
